# Can it be improved? Help me to fix this code

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, tikz-styles

[image][image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5);%
% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    {
    %\draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);
    \draw[#1]([shift=(#3:#5)]#2) arc (#3:#4:#5);
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centerarc[black,line width=5](0,0)(45:90:1cm);
\centerarc[black,line width=5](0,0)(135:180:1cm);
\centerarc[black,line width=5](0,0)(225:265:1cm);
\centerarc[black,line width=5](0,0)(315:360:1cm);
\draw [rotate=45,black,line width=5] (-1.085,0)--(1.085,0);
\draw [rotate=45,black,line width=5] (0,-1.085)--(0,1.085);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Improve in what sense? Zarko has provided more efficient and safer code. Do you want the output to look different?

Comment: Please add to the text of your question that the image should consist of two parts -- the "partially circled plus" (or whatever its name is) and the arc beneath it.  (The item in the photograph looks like a branding iron.)

Answer (score 11):

See, if this work for you:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]
\foreach \i in {0, 90, 180, 270}
\draw[rotate=\i] (0,0) -- ++ (45:1) arc (45:90:1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @esvheitemvvjin,  you are welcome. When you will have enough reputation, you can up-vote answer (by clicking on up-pen at top left side of answer), however, if answer already fulfil your expectation, you can already accept it (by clicking on check mark which also at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: @Zarko.Can you send me your own email?

Comment: @esvheitemvvjin, why? if you like to discus with me, you can invite me to own chat room or use chat room "LaTeX, TeX Friends".

Comment: again look at  before post pictures.

Comment: @esvheitemvvjin, sorry, after your edit of question, it is not clear what is the question anymore.

Comment: how to draw crescent moon

Comment: @esvheitemvvjin, please ask you new question.This is not forum site but Q&A site. I completely answered to your original question, so you should consider to accept it.